# Bazel run test binary from given directory

Tags: c++, bazel

Bazel test runner runs my test binary from the base directory of my project in its sandbox. How can I specify from where it runs my test binary file?

The reason I want to do this is that my test read some data from a text file that I pass from the data attribute to `cc_test`. so If Bazel runs my test binary file from the base directory of my project it can't find the text file and all tests failed.

Is there a way to fix it in Bazel files and don't change my code?

Comment: Specify the correct path to the file open function called from your test program. Search for `TEST_SRCDIR` in the Bazel test enyclopedia.

Comment: @pts I don't want to change the test code because we use several different build systems.

Comment: Other build systems are likely to ignore `TEST_SRCDIR`, so you can add an `if (getenv("TEST_SRCDIR"))`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack for this:

Add [Skylib](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib) as a dependency to your project, i.e. add to your `WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "b8a1527901774180afc798aeb28c4634bdccf19c4d98e7bdd1ce79d1fe9aaad7",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.4.1/bazel-skylib-1.4.1.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.4.1/bazel-skylib-1.4.1.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")

bazel_skylib_workspace()
```

Now misuse `expand_template` (a Bazel rule form Skylib) to change the filename form a relative filename to a workspace relative filename:

```
expand_template(
 name = "fix_filename",
 out = "some_file.modified.cpp",
 substitutions = {
 "my_file.txt":"my_project/package/subpackage/my_file.txt",
 },
 template = "some_file.cpp",
)
```

Change in your `cc_test` from

```
cc_test(
    name = "test1"
    srcs = ["some_file.cpp"]
)
```

to

```
expand_template(
 name = "fix_filename",
 out = "some_file.modified.cpp",
 substitutions = {
 "my_file.txt":"my_project/package/subpackage/my_file.txt",
 },
 template = "some_file.cpp",
)

cc_test(
    name = "test1"
    srcs = ["some_file.modified.cpp"]
)
```

I use this hack when a the main build system is not Bazel (e.g. make or CMake) and I do not want to break the old build system.